# ssh remote command execution and ulimit

Tags: linux, ssh, ulimit

I have the following script:

```
cat > /tmp/script.sh <<EndOfScript
#!/bin/sh
ulimit -n 8192
run_app
EndOfScript
```

which runs smoothly locally, it is always ok. But if I try to run it remotely through ssh:

```
scp /tmp/script.sh user@host:/tmp/script.sh
ssh user@host "chmod 755 /tmp/script.sh; /tmp/script.sh"
```

I got the error:

```
ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

I also tried the following command:

```
ssh user@host "ulimit -n 8192"
```

same error.

It looks like that ssh remote command execution is enforcing a 1024 hard limit on nofile limit, but I can not find out how to modify this default value. I tried to modify /etc/security/limits.conf and restart sshd, still the same error.

Comment: Finally I found the correct answer: add the following to /etc/initscript:
ulimit -c unlimited
ulimit -HSn 65535
# Execute the program.
eval exec "$4"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiannly figured out the answer: add the following to /etc/initscript

```
ulimit -c unlimited
ulimit -HSn 65535
# Execute the program.
eval exec "$4"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Strangely i cant find the options -H and -S on the ulimit man page.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of using the workaround of `/etc/initscript` (and do not make a typo in that file.. :), if you just want `sshd` to honor the settings you made in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, you should make sure you have `UsePAM yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and `/etc/pam.d/sshd` lists `session     required      pam_limits.so` (or otherwise includes another file that does so).

That should be all there is to it.

In older versions od openssh (<3.6 something) there was also a problem with UsePrivilegeSeparation that prevented limits being honored, but it was fixed in newer versions.

Comment: checked both files for those lines and they were present. Running on OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011. Still same problem as OP :|

Comment: I've been looking for this piece of information for ages now - thank you!

Comment: I have been searching for and attempting different fixes for days now and "UsePAM yes" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config is exactly what I was missing.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

`ulimit` requires superuser privileges to run.

I would suggest you to ask the server administrator to modify that value for you on the server you are trying to run the script on.

He/She can do that by modifying /etc/secutiry/limits.conf on Linux. Here is an example that might help:

```
*               soft    nofile          8192
*               hard    nofile          8192
```

After that, you don't need to restart sshd. Just logout and login again.

I would suggest you to ask the same question in [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) though. You'll get better server-side related answers there.

Comment: I modified /etc/security/limits.conf, restarted sshd, even restarted the machine. Still cannot get a nofile limit bigger than 1024.

Comment: Can you post the relevant line in your limits.conf? It might contain an error. Keep in mind that the sshd process needs to have the ulimit applied to it, so check if there's no setting of ulimit in its startup scripts etc.

Comment: I added what you want to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the start up scripts (`/etc/profile`, `~/.??*`)  for a call to `ulimit`. IIRC, once a limit has been imposed, it can't be widened anymore.

Comment: Will a restart reset the limit?

Comment: Only when the `ulimit` command isn't executed during startup. If you create a new shell window, the `ulimit` is only active for this shell and all children. In this case, starting a new shell window already creates a session without limits again. It the `ulimit` is in a startup script, all shells are affected before you can do anything, so a restart won't help. You have to disable the command, first.